# How to compare text inside cdata tag with another text?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml like-

```
<a>
<b><![CDATA[This is a text]]></b>
</a>
```

I want to see if text inside CDATA[] is same as "This is a text"?

```
<xsl:choose>                                                       
  <xsl:when test=".='<![CDATA[This is a text]]>'">
    <d>YES</d>
  </xsl:when>                                                                      
  <xsl:othewise>
   <d>NO</d>                                                         
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

But this isn't working. The expression-

```
<xsl:when test=".='This is a text'">
```

is also not working. What expression should I use?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The second one should work, but only if you are positioned on the `b` tag. If you were currently matching the `a` tag, you would need to do `<xsl:when test="b='This is a text'">`.

Comment: Also note your XSLT is not well-formed. You have typed `xsl:othewise` rather than `xsl:otherwise`, but I am assuming that is just a typo in your question. Thanks

Comment: @Tim C Yeah That was a typo in the question.

Comment: But the second one is still not working. I am sure that I am in  'b' tag. When I write 
    <xsl:value-of select="."/> it's returning "This is a text" . But using if or when for comparing it's not matching. It is always returning "NO". What should I do.

Comment: You might want to edit your question to show more of your XSLT. Ideally provide a [Minimal, Verifiable, Complete, Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiZQaFV for an example of the condition working, but it really does depend on matching the `b` node.

Comment: Does `<xsl:when test="normalize-space()='This is a text'">` work?

Comment: Thanks Tim C. Sorry for the late reply, something came up. Was unable to reproduce the error online in your linked editor . There everything seemed to work fine.  Don't know why it didn't work in my system. But, the "normalize-space()" thing works perfectly in my system too. Thanks again. If possible can you guess what might be causing this?

Comment: If you were positioned on the `a` node, then doing `.` would include whitespace (the line break before `b` for example).

Comment: Yeah that explains it. In my original code, tag 'b' was split in three lines, and here I typed in same line. Thanks a lot again.